# $_REQUEST showing garbage values

Tags: php

I have a strange issue and could not find the reason.

I have url

http://example.com/cp/user_detail?userID=2

So If I print this code

```
            print_r($_REQUST);
```

it should not print

```
             Array ( [userID] => 2 ...... ?
```

But its printing this array

```
       Array ( [userID] => 84ac17a3690b4ecd8c8abfba8687e750 [_pk_id_2_2fa0] =>  
       26c324a269691d77.1410515405.1.1410515405.1410515405. [__utma] => 
       24293118.939351632.1410515405.1410515405.1410515405.1 [__utmz] =>  
      24293118.1410515405.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) 
      [PHPSESSID] => 0394d01235809edd26422eedc400b6b5 )
```

Is it not strange?

I have a general function for getting get or post value

```
 function chf($value)
  {
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$value]))
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$value]))
        {
            $value=$_POST[$value];
        }

        else

        {
        $value=$_REQUEST[$value];
        }

        $keywords=array();

        $keywords=array('update','delete','select');

        foreach($keywords as $key=>$val)

        {

            $value= str_replace($val,'',$value);

        }

        return $value;

    }
    else
    {
        return '';  

    }
}
```

How should I changed it so it gives me correct string values?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_REQUEST includes cookies by default: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php . The PHPSESSID, __utm* are cookies. If you want just the URL parameters use $_GET.

Comment: So its overwrite $_GET values?

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the values in $_GET. However, if the names of URL parameters and cookies / POST parameters conflict, which value is used for $_REQUEST is determined by the PHP configuration directive variables_order or request_order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want data from your URL you should use

```
print_r($_GET);
```

This wil give you an array like:

```
Array(
    [userID] => 2
)
```